# Populate a JSON into a table in real time with JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, json, real-time

I'm looking for a library which do this :

- Retrieve a JSON through an AJAX call
- Populate table with the JSON
- Update in real time the table with the JSON (call every x seconds) and only delete or hide the rows wich are deleted or insert the new rows.

/Editing after first answer

Ok I guess my first explanation was not good.
Retrieving through jQuery a JSON and build a table is good, I could do that, but my request was more on the other part. 
I'm looking for a library to display the result in a special way. 
Let me explain.

Json request 1 send :
1;Tomato 2;Apple 3;Salad 4;Carot

Json request 2 send :
1;Tomato 3;Salad 4;Carot 5;Potatoes

I would like the second row disapear with a effect (fadeOut) and the rows below move Up. For the row 5, i just want a new row appears with a fade in.

Is that more clear?

Is there any library existing doing this?

I'm doing it in PHP, but i hope to write all this in JS.

The user could just look the table and see the new rows appearing and the old rows deleting.

Any ideas or am I supposed to write it from scratch?

Comment: Which web framework are you developing with? -- And writing this from scratch is incredibly easy, I can provide code if you let me know which framework you need this with.

Comment: To perform an AJAX call, JQuery needs to post somewhere. Are you coding in PHP, ASP.NET, what?

Comment: really sorry, php ...can't believe i did not mention id (editing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something friendly and full of various useful features, you can use jQuery plugin called DataTables.

It provides API allowing you to provide new data from the server on request: http://www.datatables.net/api

It works for simple implementations also, is pretty customizable, allows to change its outlook etc.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Ok i guess my first explanation was not good. Retrieving through jquery a json and build a table is good, i could do that, but my request was more on the other part. I'm looking for a library to display the result in a special way. LEt me explain. 

Json request 1 send : 
1;Tomato
2;Apple
3;Salad
4;Carot

Json request 2 send : 
1;Tomato
3;Salad
4;Carot
5;Potatoes

I would like the second row disapear with a effect (fadeOut) and the rows below move Up.
For the row 5, i just want a new row appears with a fade in.
<br>
Is that more clear ? 

Is there any livrary existing doing this ?Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can get the json like this (use `get` or `post`, ill show post here):

```
function do_json_live(){
   $.post('url.php','somedata', function(returnJSON){
     alert(returnJSON); 
     //do something with the `returnJSON`
     setTimeout(do_json_live, 2000); //2000 ms = 2 seconds
   },'json');
}
```

Comment: the problem is not to retrieve the json but to upadte the table in a friendly way

Comment: @Nicolas, all depends on what you consider 'friendly' and what your json is. i left that open for you, but got you started on the ajax side

Comment: I have a live page that i used to maintain with this type of method, but i switched to comet most recently

Comment: Ok i guess my first explanation was not good. Retrieving through jquery a json and build a table is good, i could do that, but my request was more on the other part. I'm looking for a library to display the result in a special way.

Comment: Ok i guess my first explanation was not good. Retrieving through jquery a json and build a table is good, i could do that, but my request was more on the other part. I'm looking for a library to display the result in a special way. LEt me explain. 

Json request 1 send : 
1;Tomato
2;Apple
3;Salad
4;Carot

Json request 2 send : 
1;Tomato
3;Salad
4;Carot
5;Potatoes

I would like the second row disapear with a effect (fadeOut) and the rows below move Up.
For the row 5, i just want a new row appears with a fade in.

Is that more clear ? 

Is there any livrary existing doing this ?Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really good article on different polling/comet techniques that you will want to look into. It breifly describes each and points out some pitfalls you might not think of.: http://query7.com/avoiding-long-polling. Also here is a jquery plugin for long polling: http://enfranchisedmind.com/blog/posts/jquery-periodicalupdater-ajax-polling/

Answer (score 1):

Try [Jquery Grid Plugin](http://www.trirand.com/blog/). You can retrieve JSON from server and build a grid on the client side. Take a look at the web site, there are some examples including php.

Answer (score 0):

First I would read [this](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/), but the code is actually really simple.

On your front end, you'd have your table

```
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

Then you'd make your AJAX post within JQuery

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourphpfile",
  data: <data you want your php file to read>
  success: function(data){
    $('#myTable').html(data);
  }
});
```

Your method in php would take in your posted `data`, it would create an `HTML` string of a `table` element, and then you'd set your `table`'s `innerHTML` on the front end with `.html()` built into JQuery -- that way you never have to worry about showing/hiding, everytime you post, your given the `table` itself, so you just display exactly that, you can handle all the fancy stuff server side.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the awesome [jqGrid plugin](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).

To do the autorefresh, you should do this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $("#grid1").trigger("reloadGrid");
}, 10000);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: i checked the jqgrid but i'm not sure it does what i need. (see the edit part of my original post)

Answer (score 0):

If real-time updating is truly required, as Neal suggested, Comet or Stream-Hub would be one avenue worth checking into.

As for the interface, I recently have been using JQuery Templates, and when reconciling added / removed / updated records, I use JQuery selectors to clear & update, and use Templates to add in new records.  And because I'm using JQuery in all 3 events, I could easily integrate their motion / visual effects.

[JQuery Templates](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx)

[JQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

[JQuery Effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

[Stream-Hub](http://www.stream-hub.com/)

I myself only needed polling (every 15 seconds) so I'm using Robert Fischer's improved JQuery PeriodicalUpdater

[JQuery Periodical Updater](https://github.com/RobertFischer/JQuery-PeriodicalUpdater)